# ValueError in python exception: how to handle while user input is nested in argument of function. Want to return message when exception occurs

Tags: python

My problem here is that if the user inputs a value that is not an integer, it throws a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'example'`
i want to handle this exception if the user inputs a string or float based value and return `print("Sorry thats not right, try again")` and replay the function.
how can this be accomplished?
I fear it is because the input function is posed as an argument inside the configselect() function that this might not be possible?

```
choice = [1, 2, 3]


def configselect(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        print("you chose 962")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("you chose Audience")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("you chose mAP")
    else:
        print('Thats not a valid Number. Please try Again.')


configselect(int(input("Are you configuring a (1)962, (2)Audience, or (3)mAP? ")))
```

Comment: Of course, you need to check if is it a number or not before you pass the argument. ```int()``` cannot convert letters or symbols the integer

Comment: You catch it like any other exception. Do you know what exceptions are? Do you know what `try ... except` is?

Comment: Read 1. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions or 2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `try...except ValueError`, as a `ValueError` is raised when integer cannot convert something to an integer

```
choice = [1, 2, 3]


def configselect(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        print("you chose 962")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("you chose Audience")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("you chose mAP")
    
while True:
    try:
        val=int(input("Are you configuring a (1)962, (2)Audience, or (3)mAP? "))
        if val in choice:
            configselect(val)
            break
        else:
            print("Please select either 1,2 or 3")
    except ValueError:
        print('Thats not a valid Number. Please try Again.')
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much, earlier i had tried the try/except inside of the function and my issue was that the value was hitting the exception before it ever made it to the try/except. cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the exception, you need to add a `try`-`except` block:

```
try:
    configselect(int(input("Are you configuring a (1)962, (2)Audience, or (3)mAP? ")))
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, that's not right, try again")
```

If you want to prompt for input continuously until the user enters something acceptable, you need to wrap this in a loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        configselect(int(input("Are you configuring a (1)962, (2)Audience, or (3)mAP? ")))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, that's not right, try again")
    else:
        break
```